# Editar dataTable na caixa Dialog em JavaWeb - JSF

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate

Preciso editar uma linha do dataTable quando abrir a caixa de dialogo, mas não está funcionando do jeito que estou fazendo, eu fiz um teste no console, e o objeto fica null quando envio a edição dele, é como se não carregasse.

Imagem para demonstrar o que quero:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

DataTable:

```
<p:dataTable emptyMessage="Nenhum registro salvo !"
 filteredValue="#{projetoBean.listaProjetosFiltrados}"
 value="#{projetoBean.listaProjetos}" var="projeto" rows="5" paginator="true" >

<p:column headerText="Porcentagem de Conclusão:">
<p:commandButton value="#{projeto.porcentagem}" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();"  >
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{projetoBean.projetoCadastro}"
                     value="#{projeto}"/>
</p:commandButton>
</p:column>     

</p:dataTable>
```

Dialog:

```
<h:form>
<p:dialog header="Editar Porcentagem" widgetVar="dlg1" minHeight="40">
     <h:outputText value="Digite a nova porcentagem" />
         <p:inputText maxlength="3" value="#{projetoBean.projetoCadastro.porcentagem}"/> 
    <p:commandButton value="Salvar" actionListener="#{projetoBean.editar}" update=":msgGlobal"/>
</p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped

public class ProjetoBean {
private String acao;
private Long idProjeto;
private Projeto projetoCadastro;
private List<Projeto> listaProjetos;
private List<Projeto> listaProjetosFiltrados;
private List<Usuario> listaUsuarios;
private List<Cliente> listaClientes;

//GetSet

public void limpar() {
    projetoCadastro = new Projeto();
}

public void criar() {

    try {
        ProjetoDAO projetodao = new ProjetoDAO();
        projetodao.salvar(projetoCadastro);

        projetoCadastro = new Projeto();

        FacesUtil.addMsgInfo("Projeto criado com sucesso !");
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        FacesUtil.addMsgErro("Erro ao tentar incluir um projeto");
    }

}

public void carregarPesquisa() {

    try {       
        ProjetoDAO projetodao = new ProjetoDAO();
        listaProjetos = projetodao.listar();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        FacesUtil.addMsgErro("Erro ao listar Projetos");
    }

}

public void carregarCadastro(){

    try {       
        if(idProjeto != null){
            ProjetoDAO projetodao = new ProjetoDAO();       
            projetoCadastro = projetodao.buscarId(idProjeto);   
        } else {
            projetoCadastro = new Projeto();
        }

        UsuarioDAO usuariodao = new UsuarioDAO();   
        listaUsuarios = usuariodao.listar();

        ClienteDAO clientedao = new ClienteDAO();   
        listaClientes = clientedao.listar();

    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        FacesUtil.addMsgErro("Erro ao tentar obter dados do projeto.");
    }

}

public void excluir() {

    try {
        ProjetoDAO projetodao = new ProjetoDAO();
        projetodao.excluir(projetoCadastro);

        FacesUtil.addMsgInfo("Projeto removido com sucesso !");
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        FacesUtil.addMsgErro("Erro ao tentar remover um projeto.");
    }

}

public void editar() {

    try {
        ProjetoDAO projetodao = new ProjetoDAO();
        projetodao.editar(projetoCadastro);
        System.out.println(projetoCadastro);
        FacesUtil.addMsgInfo("Projeto editado com sucesso !");
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        FacesUtil.addMsgErro("Erro ao tentar editar um projeto.");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Já tentou fazer um update no dialog a partir do command button? Pode ser que ele não esteja sendo atualizado.